# how to check date can not be less than current date using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, datepicker

I am using jquery date picker in textbox and i want the user cannot select the date less than current. I am new to jquery/javascript. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to disable past dates then:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the datepickers minDate variable to the current date (http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date() });`

Answer (score 1):

Here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You can see that datepicker has options for

```
maxDateDate: Number, StringDefault:null
minDateDate: Number, StringDefault:null
```